# JQuery Ajax and Mobile SAafari Authentication

Tags: ios

So i am trying to get a JSON Request, which needs authentication, this worked on Desktop, but on iOS i get an Username/Password Dialog each time i access it, how can i surpass this on iOS? It seems the Username / Password Settings are not used or not performed well

here is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.someservice.json',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
              username: 'user',
              password: 'pass'
            },
            username: "user",
            password: "pass",
            success: function(content) { 
                //proceed(content);
                proceed(content[0]); 
            }});
    })
```

Can someone plz correct this to not to get asked for Authentication each time ? thx in advance